# Why is the maximum value of my calculator $10^{100}$?

Tags: calculator, floating-point

The maximum value I can have in my calculator is $10^{100}$. At first it seems right but when we consider that the calculator should stores its number as binary, this seems weird.

Why isn't the maximum exponent a base 2 number? Is this limit set manually in the calculator when building it?

Calculator used: Sharp EL-W516X (WriteView)

Comment: Are you sure that calculator actually uses binary internally?

Comment: @Henning Makholm Not at all, you can consider that part of the question. It's just what makes me wonder in the first place.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't know about the Sharp in particular, but it's not unusual for calculators to work in base ten internally (actually [binary coded decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal), of course).

Among the advantages of doing so are

- You don't need to do (moderately complex) conversions between decimal and binary for entering or displaying numbers,
- It naturally avoids the most embarrassing rounding errors where, say, $0.003\times 2000-6$ fails to equal $0$.
- It makes it easy to *explain* to your customers how many digits of precision they can expect in their calculations.

The main disadvantage relative to binary is that it takes slightly more work to calculate with a given precision. But raw calculation time is not really an issue for simple non-programmable calculators, and the effort saved by binary would be taken up again by needing to do binary-to-decimal conversions whenever you display anything.

Higher-end graphing or programmable calculators will be somewhat more likely to use binary arithmetic for performance.

---

All that said, it is still pretty likely that you calculator represents the *exponent* in pure binary internally.  Limiting the exponent range to two digits could well have more pragmatic reasons, such as

- Being sure that every representable number can fit in the calculator's display.
- Leaving some additional range for intermediaries such that you can be sure that internal computations will not overflow as long as inputs and outputs are within the officially supported range.
- Because market research told them that, among those users who are likely to complain about a limit they don't understand, those who complain *most obnoxiously* tend to be those who find 127 a stranger limit than 99.

Comment: Also keep in mind that some industries (especially finance) actually require the use of BCD for fear of rounding errors and a "Superman III" scenario.